# JSON stored in SUPER type fails to select camelcase element. Too long to be serialized. How can I select?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, nested, amazon-redshift

### Summary:

I am working with a large JSON that is stored in a redshift `SUPER` type.

### Context

This issue is near identical to the question posted here for TSQL. My schema:

chainId BIGINT
properties SUPER

Sample data:

{
"chainId": 5,
"$browser": "Chrome",
"token": "123x5"
}

I have this as a column in my table called properties.

### Desired behavior

I want to be able to retrieve the value `5` from the `chainId` key and store it in a BIGINT column.

#### What I've tried

I have referenced the following aws docs:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-overview.html
```

I have tried the following which haven't worked for me:

```
SELECT
 properties.chainId::varchar as test1
     , properties.chainId as test2
     , properties.chainid as test3
     , properties."chainId" as test4
     , properties."chainid" as test5
     , json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(properties), 'chainId') serial_then_extract
     , properties[0].chainId as testval1
     , properties[0]."chainId" as testval2
     , properties[0].chainid as testval3
     , properties[0]."chainid" as testval4
     , properties[1].chainId as testval5
     , properties[1]."chainId" as testval6
FROM clean
```

Of these, the attempt, `serial_then_extract` returned a not null, correct value, but not all of the values in my `properties` field are short enough to serialize, so this only works on some of the rows.

All others return `null`.

Referencing the following docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest I have also attempted to iterate over the super type using partisql:

```sql
SELECT ps.*
    , p.chainId
from clean ps, ps.properties p
where 1=1
```

But this returns no rows.

I also tried the following:

select
properties
, properties.token
, properties."$os"
from base

And this returned rows with values. I know that there is a `chainId` value as I've checked the corresponding key and am working with sample data.

What am I missing? What else should I be trying?

Does anyone know if this has to do with the way that the JSON key is formatted? [camelcase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the best approach is to enable `enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute`  like so:

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute to TRUE;
 -- Accessing JSON attribute names with uppercase and mixedcase names
```

For your case, this is better than `enable_case_sensitive_identifier`, since that flag affects databases, tables, columns, etc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-configurations.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable case sensitive identifiers.  By default Redshift maps everything to lower case for table and column names.  If you have mixed case identifiers like in your super field you need to enable case sensitivity with

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_case_sensitive_identifier.html